# Remove array1 values based on match of array2 values

Tags: php, arrays, match

`updated question with array structure and result expectation`

```
$arr1=array(
            'string',
            'string 1',
            'string 2',
            'return this'
        );

$arr2=array(
            'string'
        );
```

I want to end up with this:

```
array(1) { [1]=> string(11) "return this" }
```

I tried `array_diff`.

```
array_diff($arr1,$arr2);
```

And it returns this:

```
array(3) { [1]=> string(8) "string 1" [2]=> string(8) "string 2" [3]=> string(11) "return this" }
```

`this works`
I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but this is what I have working now.

```
        $list=array(
            'return this',
            'do not return this string',
            'string'
        );
        $exceptions=array(
            'string'
        );
        foreach($list as $key=>$value) {
            foreach($exceptions as $e) {
                if(strpos($value,$e) !== false ) unset($list[$key]);
            }
        }
```

The result:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "return this" }
```

Comment: Better share your array structure here. So you will get quick answers.

Comment: Jonathan, PHP has a bunch of in-build functions to do these kinds of things for you and docs are a great source of info for these kinds of questions. Have a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: Yes, I do know this @Pappa. I've read the docs and still struggling with this particular situation. I don't think people here actually read sentences - they need to see <code>code blocks</code> because English is more difficult to understand.

Comment: @Jonathan Please add some code example. Then only some one will try it and help you.

Comment: I improved the question, so hopefully can get some better feedback now? Thanks.

Comment: Can someone please take this off `hold`?

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your edit maybe you want [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($list,function($arrayElement){
                     return !in_array($arrayElement,$my_exceptions);
                 });
```

array_filter takes an array and a callback function. In the callback function you are passed one of the array elements. The callback then needs to return true or false, return true will pass the current array element into the filtered array, return false will keep it out.

Since you want to check if any of the array elements from `$list` are in `$my_exceptions` you check to see if it is in the array using `in_array`, if it is in the array return false so it gets filtered out.

Though `array_diff`  should do the same thing in this case

```
$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4);
$arr2 = array(1,2,3);

$result = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
```

`$result` here would be an array containing a single element which would be `4`

Comment: Why we need to do merge..??

Comment: @Gautam3164 he must have edited the question there was something about needing to add to an $array3 variable or maybe i miss read

Comment: @Gautam3164 this doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe take a look at my updated question.

Comment: @PatrickEvans - I revised my question with more relevant info. Hopefully the question makes more sense now, and someone can take this off `hold`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `array_diff` like

```
array_diff($arr1 , $arr2);
```

See this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: `array_diff` seems to do literal match. I need to remove values from $arr1 that contain a value in $arr2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(10, 20, 30);
$arr2 = array(5, 20, 30, 40);
foreach($arr2 as $chk_arr){
    if(!in_array($chk_arr, $arr1)) {
        $arr3[] = $chk_arr;
    }
}  

print_r($arr3);
```

Comment: This just returns the list of exception. Thanks.